# ERROR CREATING REACT APP WITH npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs

it won't let me install react because this error comes out
i am trying to install react but i get this error message

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT

npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT

npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/html-webpack-plugin: Socket timeout

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hector\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-08T01_35_21_593Z-debug-0.log


Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
```

I already tried clearing the cache

Answer (score 1):

Try `npx create-react-app client`. The word client can be replaced with any word you would like to be the name of your folder.